# How do I safely 'close' or destroy a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm putting together a modular editor form. The main editor component dynamically renders text, check box, and select fields, depending on what item (in a list) it is targeting. The editor component is rendered via a function in the page's main component:

```
if(this.state.isEditing) return (
    <ReForm.Editor key={this.state.editTarget.id} editTarget={this.state.editTarget} map={appointmentMap}/>
)
```

When an editable item is clicked by the user, `this.state.editTarget` is updated and `isEditing` is set to true, thus rendering the editor.

At this point there is no issue. I can edit the editor's state with `this.setState()`, and when I save the edits, they are properly pushed onward through a Flux-like pipe to my database.

The problem arises after I've closed the editor and re-opened it. Closing the editor simply involves setting the page's `this.state.isEditing` to false, which unmounts the editor component. Re-opening the editor view is exactly the same process as before, but now when a value in the editor is changed via `this.setState()`, the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: replaceState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.
```

`true` is returned when `this.isMounted()` is run from the editor's `componentDidMount` callback.

However, `false` is returned by `this.isMounted()` when run right before attempting to `setState()`

This only happens after I've closed and re-opened the editor, so I'm thinking that this is related to how to safely 'close' or destroy a React component.

Comment: Could the child components of the re-rendered editor be attempting to reference the previous instance of the editor?

Comment: I set the editor component's key to the current UTC time and re-ran the above scenario. The child components are indeed trying to call the old editor component's `setState()` function.

Comment: Do you even need to set a key here? I'd try debugging the componentDidMount methods on the editor's child components

Comment: @ApplePi, please provide more code.  It's likely a simple fix.

Comment: seems like some listeners aren't properly detached in `componentWillUnmount`